# Installation issues with VirtualBox 6.1 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

Having problems installing VirtualBox 6.1 on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.  Here is what I get in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox : Depends: libgsoap-2.8.91 but it is not installable
              Depends: liblzf1 (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
              Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas?